# RSA: why does $m^{ed}$ equal the original message?

Tags: rsa, public-key

Trapdoor functions are defined as that a secret key reverses the function. It seems to me more that it causes a cycle to repeat, similar to how $n^k \bmod k$, when $k$ is a prime number, equals $n$, and $n^k+1 \bmod k$ equals $n^2 \bmod k$, a cyclical pattern.

What is the reason $m^{ed}$ in RSA equals the original message? Is it in some way similar to $n^k \bmod k = n$ (when $k$ is a prime number)?

Comment: '$n^k+1 \bmod k$ equals $n^2$' - no, it doesn't.  Perhaps you meant $n^{k+1} \bmod k$ maybe???

Comment: Fermat's little theorem $n^k \equiv n \pmod k$ holds when $k$ is prime.  A more general statement is Euler's theorem: that $n^{\ell \cdot \phi(k) + 1} \equiv n \pmod k$ for any $k$ and $\ell$, where $\phi$ is Euler's totient function.  As it happens, $e \cdot d = \ell \cdot \phi(k) + 1$ for some $\ell$, because by construction $e \cdot d \equiv 1 \pmod{\phi(k)}$.

Comment: Ok so Fermat's little theorem is just the observation that a^p mod p = a, the same observation I have made when trying to understand RSA. That explains a bit conceptually how it relates to the rest of what I have tried to learn. In what context did Fermat make the observation?

Comment: and is there also a mathematical pattern that a^n mod p = a^(p+n) mod p?

Comment: @grday No, but you're close: $a^{p + n} \equiv a^p a^n \equiv a a^n \equiv a^{1 + n} \pmod p$.  You can think of exponents as integers mod $\phi(p) = p - 1$ in this case: if two exponents $n$ and $m$ have $n \equiv m \pmod{\phi(p)}$, then $a^n \equiv a^m \pmod p$.

Comment: ah yes, since a^p mod p == a == a^1

Comment: I have infinitely much to learn to understand digital signatures, baby steps

Answer (score 1):

> Trapdoor functions are defined as that a secret key reverses the function. It seems to me more that it causes a cycle to repeat

I don't know if that's a useful way to think of trapdoor functions; one counterexample would be the trapdoors within multivariate public key cryptosystems; they certainly are trapdoor functions, however there isn't anything like a cycle going on.  In fact, the only examples of trapdoor functions that act "in a cycle" would be RSA and related systems.

In any case, on to your real question:

> What is the reason $m^{e^d}$  in RSA equals the original message? Is it in some way similar to $n^k \bmod k = n$ (when $k$ is a prime number)?

Actually, it's not only similar, it follows directly.

Modifying the variable names (to me, $p$ is a prime, $k$ is an arbitrary integer), we generalize $m^p \bmod p = m$ to more general statement $m^{1 + k(p-1)} \equiv m \pmod p$; this can be shown by the relations $m^1 \equiv m \pmod p$ (trivial) and $m^p \equiv m \pmod p$ (Fermat's Little Theorem) and induction.

In addition, we have $(m^e)^d$ is the same as $m^{e \cdot d}$.

And, we have selected $d, e$ so that $e \cdot d \equiv 1 \pmod{ p-1 }$ and $e \cdot d \equiv \pmod{q - 1}$ (where $p, q$ are the prime factors of $n$.

What $e \cdot d \equiv 1 \pmod{p-1}$ means is that there is an integer $k$ such that $e \cdot d = 1 + k(p-1)$.  So, we have $m^{ed} = m^{1 + (p-1)}$, and so by the above logic, we know that is the same as $m$ modulo $p$

The same logic shows that $m^{ed} \equiv m \pmod q$.

Combining the above two with the Chinese Remainder Theorem (with $p, q$ being relatively prime), we get $m^{e \cdot d} \equiv m \pmod{n}$; if the original message is less than $n$ (the modulus size), we get $(m^e)^d \pmod n = m$, QED

Comment: Actually that may be my mistake (I edited the question) that it's written as ${m}^{{e}^{d}}$ instead of $m^{ed}$.

Comment: @AleksanderRas: actually, it's not (necessarily a mistake); encrypting a message $m$ is $m^e$ (modulo $n$), and so encrypting and then decrypting the message is $(m^e)^d$ (modulo $n$).  Now, that's the same as $m^{e \cdot d}$, but writing the former is not a mistake

Comment: Ah yes, of course, $e$ and $d$ are multiplied, not added. Forgot the basics of exponential math...

Comment: @AleksanderRas i had written m^e^d so not your mistake